# change of time zone when calculating the duration of the flight from origin city to destination city

Tags: asp.net-2.0

i am working on a Airlline reservation system.I came with a query in which i want to display the duration of flight from origin city to destination city, both are in different time zones. How can i handle this problem.

```
                                             SIJO A J
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert both times to UTC and see how long the flight takes.